# Paypal recurring_payment_skipped conditions

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

When using the Paypal Express Checkout API, I've created a recurring payments profile, and set up an endpoint to listen for IPN messages.

I've received messages at this endpoint with a `txn_type` of `recurring_payment_skipped`.

The [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/) is a little sparse on the details of when these messages may occur:

`Recurring payment skipped; it will be retried up to 3 times, 5 days apart`

What would cause a recurring payment to be skipped?  What happens after the 3rd retry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skipped basically means failed.  This could be due to the funding source(s) available (or not available) on the payer's account, it could be something like a daily limit reached on the payer's credit card, or anything else that would keep the payment from completing.

After the 3rd retry if it hasn't completed successfully it will automatically suspend the profile.  At that point you would have to collect the outstanding balance and then you could reactivate the profile.

Comment: The ridiculous thing is that you don't know whether they're going to pay or not.